# Visual Studio cannot find System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, xmlhttprequest

I am adding `System.Net.Http` and `System.Net` but I can't create an `HttpRequestMessage` object. (I am trying to inherit `SelectController` function from `DefaultHttpControllerSelector` Class)

Comment: Try adding this nuget package "System.Net.Http". OR change your target framework to 4.xx

Comment: I tried it already but it not refined. But then, I restarted computer and it refined itself. Thank you for comment:)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because restart of user's machine solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I restart my computer it repaired by itself.